# Wait for an Active Directory query to finish before executing next line

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to work out how I can make the below code:

- Wait for line 1 to complete before continuing.
- Wait for line 4 to complete before running line 5

.

```
   $invokevar = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $searchbase | select -Expand dnshostname
   New-Variable -name "invoke$dom" -value $invokevar -Force
   $fullvar = Get-Variable -Name "invoke$dom" -ValueOnly
   $results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $fullvar -ScriptBlock $sbmain
   $badhosts = Compare-Object $($invokevar | Sort-Object) $($results | select -expand pscomputername | Sort-Object) | select -expand InputObject
```

Having a mental block, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In powershell, the script executes line by line
Unless or until the execution of line 1 finishes, the script wont go for line 2.
So ideally you shouldn't be worrying about the problem stated above.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For internal commands PowerShell does wait before starting the next command. One exception to this rule is external Windows subsystem based *EXE* applications, you can apply *out-null*

PowerShell will wait until the *exe* process has been exited before continuing. 
You can also use *Start-Process* with the *-Wait* parameter:

```
Start-Process <path to exe> -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

If you are using the PowerShell Community Extensions version it is:

```
$proc = Start-Process <path to exe> -NoWindow
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

Another option in **PowerShell 2.0** is to use a background job:

```
$job = Start-Job { invoke command here }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

In your case it will wait for the execution to get completed. Else you can check the status using a **do-While** loop and keep on adding a **start-sleep of 1 sec**

Hope this approach helps you.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks very much for your information & help.

Answer (score -2):

Those answers are wrong. Get-ADUser absolutely may return data in the middle of the script down the line..

1. Some get-aduser command
2. echo "some string"

I have seen output line 2 first and then the results from line 1.

The only way around this is to assign a variable to the query and process the variable.

1. $string = get-aduser....
2. process $string
3. echo "some string"

This will process in order 1,2,3 without failure.

Comment: you are talking about the _display delay_ when mixing direct-to-host writes and indirect success stream output that _eventually_ gets to the host. that is not what the OP asked about.